# Find browser exact version for IE11 as default edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I require to find exact browser version which should find the browser use IE 11 as edge in emulation. 
Windows7 IE 11 version has default emulation as Edge. And when we try to find the browser version its return IE 11 only. (Since the real browser is IE 11). But I need to find or understand the browser currently running on IE11 as edge and not an IE 11!!

Fyr, The code tried.

```
function Check_Version(){
var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.

if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){

   var ua = navigator.userAgent,
       re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\\.0-9]{0,})");

   if (re.exec(ua) !== null){
     rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
   }
}
else if(navigator.appName == "Netscape"){                       
   /// in IE 11 the navigator.appVersion says 'trident'
   /// in Edge the navigator.appVersion does not say trident
   if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident') === -1) rv = 12;
   else rv = 11;
}       

return rv;
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `document.documentMode`

Comment: I dont want change anything on browser F12 option.. Just need to find the IE currently holding edge details.

Comment: If that comment was to me, no clue what you are talking about. I just gave a suggestion to see what is logged in `document.documentMode` and to see if it meets your needs.